# Site not displaying properly

Tags: asp.net, localhost, iis-7.5

I created a webforms asp.net site. When I run the site from VWD 2008 express the site displays fine. But I setup the site on IIS 7.5 on localhost. Now when I browse the site I get a page filled with symbols.

Eg.

��{���{��;�N'���

What is going on here?

Comment: may be something is wrong with the localization settings ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I changed sites settings from DefaultAppPool to Classic .NET AppPool.